# Program not valid and attribs not setup correctly

Tags: javascript, webgl

Here's my code for initializing the program;

```
function initializeProgram() {
    vertexShader = util.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
    fragmentShader = util.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);
    shaderList = [vertexShader, fragmentShader];

    shaderProgram = util.createProgram(shaderList);
}
```

and here's my loop;

```
function loop() {
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 4, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

The issue I'm having here is getting two errors at two points;

```
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram); // WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attribs not setup correctly
```

I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting these warnings, I've been trying to port C OpenGL to WebGL so my main guess is that there are naming/argument differences

The full code is located at;

script.js - http://pastebin.com/zYyQY3Bi
util.js - http://pastebin.com/ihEFQxaB

Answer (score 3):

```
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram); 
// WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
```

Most likely means your shaders didn't compile because they have errors. You can get the error with

```
gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader)
```

And also possibly

```
gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
```

They each return a string so something like this is common

```
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) (
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    // exit? alert?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `layout` keyword is not supported in WebGL (supports only OpenGL ES2, not desktop OpenGL/GLSL). You need to remove it to get your shader to compile.
- The program has not been compiled or linked (calls to `compileShader`, `linkProgram`).  A simple code snippet that shows the flow is at http://www.gpupowered.org/sand2/launch2/programs.js